# Add GLFW source code directly to the project on Windows

Tags: c++, c, glfw

I'm trying to add GLFW to a Visual Studio project without first building it into a binary .lib file, that is, I'm adding the entire GLFW source files to the project:

1. I created a Visual Studio 2022 project.
2. Added GLFW source files there
3. Attached header files:

   ```
   #include <glad/gl.h>

   #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
   ```
4. Added preprocessor definition:

   ```
   _GLFW_WIN32;
   _GLFW_OPENGL_LIBRARY
   ```
5. I click compile and the compiler produces a lot and a lot of errors:

   ```
   -C1083 Cannot open include file: X11/cursorfont.h: No such file or directory
   -C2039 "x11": Not a member of "_GLFWlibrary".
   -C4013 DisplayWidthMM: no definition; assumes "extern" with return type "int"
   -C2065 screens: undeclared GLFW identifier
   -C1083 Cannot open include file: unistd.h: No such file or directory
   ....
   ```

What did I forget to do? What preprocessor definitions forgot to add? Or what's going on? :(

**PS_1**:

In file GLFW `x11_windows.c` - GLFW tries to `#include <X11/cursorfont.h>` - but there is no such file in GLFW source files.

And why is GLFW trying to enable X11 on Windows?

Comment: " a lot of errors" is not a diagnostic that will help us help you. Please edit your question with the first handful of lines from the full compiler output.

Comment: Did you just dump the whole GLFW directory wholesale into your project? That will by definition also include files only meant to be compiled on the X11 platform. See the [GLFW CMake definitions](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt) for a list. Honestly, you are better off just building GLFW with CMake or taking in a binary distribution. If you continue down the current path you will just end up approximating the build process and -parameters currently encoded in CMake.

Comment: @Botje, yes you are right i did that. Thank you! Now I understand what was my mistake.

Comment: @Botje, I'm curious why the author of glfw - just didn't do in the files responsible for Unix, for example, just #if defined(_GNU_subsystem), then include the necessary files, etc.
And then it would be possible to add all the files to the project simply and that's it. After all, if do that, then it would work?

Comment: Because "the author of GLFW" delegated that responsibility to the build system, which is in charge of figuring out which dependencies are available (and where) and making them available to the compilation process. This is not trivially solved by conditional compilation.